# Create HTML Table with multiple python lists

Tags: python, html, list, html-table

I have three lists and would like to write them into a html file to create a table.

My lists are:
host, ip, sshkey

I already tried:

```
with open("index.html", "a") as file:
    for line in host:
        file.write("<tr><td>" + line + "</td><td>" + ip + " </td><td> + sshkey + "</td>"
file.close()
```

I got the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

And when I try:

```
  file.write("<tr><td>" + line + "</td><td>" + ip[0] + " </td><td> + sshkey[0] + "</td>"
```

I get this:

```
Hostname1 IP1 SSHkey1
Hostname2 IP1 SSHkey1
Hostname3 IP1 SSHkey1
```

But I want this outcome:

```
Hostname1 IP1 SSHkey1
Hostname2 IP2 SSHkey2
Hostname3 IP3 SSHkey3
```

Comment: Does this not produce some type of a syntax error? You're missing a closing bracket and a quote. I believe you want `file.write("<tr><td>" + line + "</td><td>" + ip + " </td><td>" + sshkey + "</td>")`.

Comment: You can add a count for `sshkey` which will change its value and you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're iterating over one list when doing `for line in host:`.

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate through all of the lists simultaneously.

```
with open("index.html", "a") as file:
    for h, i, k in zip(host, ip, sshkey):
        file.write("<tr><td>" + h + "</td><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + k + "</td>")
```

Also, you had a few syntax errors in your code, which I updated. Missing quotes, closing parenthesis, and a redundant file close which happens automagically utilizing the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still a beginner with python so this really helped a lot! :)
Also I feel like an idiot for not copying my code correctly.. so yeah thanks for fixing my syntax errors. ^^'

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
with open("index.html", "a") as file:
for line in host:
    file.write("<tr><td>" + line + "</td><td>" + ip[i] + "</td><td>" + sshkey[0] + "</td>");
    i++;
file.close()
```